# Netbeans.conf: what is the variable for the user home?

Tags: netbeans, configuration

When starting Netbeans, I need to add a system property named mEnvironment and set it as a sub-directory of the user's home. Example: In the netbeans.conf, I would like to add:

netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-DmEnvironment=${USER_HOME}/mySubDirectory ......

USER_HOME is given as example of course.

Does someone know how Netbeans get the user home directory in the netbeans.conf file?

Thank you

Paul

Answer (score 0):

> Does someone know how Netbeans get the user home directory in the
>   netbeans.conf file?

The process is convoluted, and varies by operating system, but is described in great detail within **netbeans.conf** itself. This is the relevant content for my Apache NetBeans 11.1 installation:

```
# On Windows ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "<AppData>\NetBeans" where <AppData> is user's
# value of "AppData" key in Windows Registry under
# "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
# and ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "<Local AppData>\NetBeans\Cache" where <Local AppData> is user's
# value of "Local AppData" key in Windows Registry under
# "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
#
# On Mac ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans" and
# ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} with "~/Library/Caches/NetBeans"
#
# On other systems ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "~/.netbeans" and ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} with "~/.cache/netbeans"
....
netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/11.1"
```

However, none of that really helps you, because you cannot access the values of `netbeans_default_userdir` or `DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT`; they are used internally by NetBeans itself, and are not System properties. You can verify this by displaying the values returned by `System.getProperties()`; none of the entries in **netbeans.conf** are shown.

Also, you can't meaningfully add new name/value pairs in **netbeans.conf**; you can only modify the values of the names used by NetBeans. That file is for NetBeans configuration, not user configuration. So if you add a line containing (say) `MyConfSetting="ABC"` then NetBeans will simply ignore that, and it won't be accessible to you either.

However, you can use an alternative approach to set a System Property for your directory in your application:

- The read-only environment variable `APPDATA` points to your (operating system's) user directory. On my Windows 10 machine it has the value `C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming`.
- The default user directory for NetBeans is the value of APPDATA + a sub-directory named `NetBeans` + a sub-directory named the NetBeans version. On my machine it is `C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.1`. See the value of **User directory** in the **Help > About** screen for confirmation.

I don't know how to dynamically determine the version of NetBeans, but if that isn't important you can programmatically create a system property specifying your directory path:

```
String dir = System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\NetBeans\\mySubDirectory";
System.setProperty("myDir", dir);
System.out.println("myDir=" + System.getProperty("myDir"));
```

On my machine that `println()` call displays `myDir=C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\mySubDirectory`. I don't know if that approach meets your requirements, but I don't know of any other simple way to dynamically set your directory name.

Notes:

- I checked this on Windows 10. Details may vary on other operating systems, but the overall approach should still work.
- You can also specify parameters at run time using **{project} > Properties > Run > Arguments** (e.g. `arg1=%APPDATA%\NetBeans\MyDir`) and **{project} > Properties > Run > VM Options** (e.g. `-Dvmopt1=%APPDATA%\NetBeans\MyDir`), but that approach won't work because the `%APPDATA%` is simply treated as the literal "%APPDATA%" rather than evaluated as an environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Long live to Netbeans